# Replace default jquery-ui.css path

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to get Yii 1.1.16 to read my custom `jQuery-ui.min.css` file instead of the one that comes by default.

I tried editing the `clientScript` in my `main.php` but cant seem to get it to work.

Here is my code

```
'components'=>array(
        'clientScript'=>array(
            'scriptMap' => array(
                'jquery-ui.css' => '/css/jquery-ui.min.css',
            ),
            'packages'=>array(
                'jquery'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'js/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
                ),
               'jquery.ui'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'',
                    'js'=>array('js/jquery-ui.min.js'),
                    'depends' => array('jquery')
                ),
            ),
```

It adds the default css everytime i call the `CJuiButton` widget. Any solutions?

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you set right config (`main.php`) for app.  `$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/config/main.php'; Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set right config (main.php) in `index.php`:

```
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/config/main.php';
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

If it doesn't work add code bellow before `zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton` widget calling:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap = array(
    'jquery-ui.css' => '/css/jquery-ui.min.css',
);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton',array(
    'buttonType'=>'submit',
    'name'=>'btnSubmit',
    'value'=>'1',
    'caption'=>'Submit form',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'ui-button-primary')
    )
);
```